# Cron Expression From Date and every interval

Tags: cron

Is it possible to generate a cron expression that says from given date-time every hour/minute/day etc?

eg:- from December 1st 2016 , every hour?

Comment: Why dont you do the date checking part in a bash script? May be the `at` command is better suited for this.

Comment: I am not using it in bash, I am generating the cron expression from UI and sending it to scala scheduler in backend.

Comment: Instead you could try adding the date check expression right inside the cron along side the script  as ```test `date +%s` > UNIX epoch of date && /path/to/code```

Comment: Again not an UNIX cron, it's quartz java cron expression